# Quick Sort algorithm, works for all but the last number?

Tags: quicksort, insertion-sort

Hello Stack Overflowers,

I'm stumped on a homework issue where we were tasked to create an "inefficient" quick sort algorithm that was easy to explain and understand using a pivot system and using a median of three technique and then using insertion sort as a cleanup sort. I will attach "SOME" code snippets as to not give away a solution to others attempting this homework, aswell as the output [edit: apparently I am not allowed to post images yet ugh..]. The only problem I am having is that in the final sorting results, the last index is the only unsorted value. the rest seems to work fine. This happens whether I go behind the threshold and just use insertion sort only, or the full quicksort. Any ideas? I've been working on this for a few days and I am probably just suffering from a lack of sleep. A point in the right direction would be wonderful!

```
int partition(int* list, int start, int stop) {

int index = 0;
int leftPtr = start;
int rightPtr = stop - 1;

while (!(leftPtr >= rightPtr)) {

    if (list[leftPtr] <= list[rightPtr]) {

        rightPtr--;

    }
    else {

        swap(list, rightPtr, leftPtr);

    }

    if (list[rightPtr] >= list[leftPtr]) {

        leftPtr++;

    }
    else {

        swap(list, leftPtr, rightPtr);

    }
}

index = leftPtr;


return index;
```

}

void quickSort(int* theArray, int startIndex, int stopIndex) {

```
if (stopIndex - startIndex <= SMALL_LIST_SIZE) {

    insertionSort(theArray, startIndex, stopIndex);
}
else {

    setMedianOfThree(theArray, startIndex, stopIndex);
    int partitionElement = partition(theArray, startIndex, stopIndex);
    quickSort(theArray, startIndex, partitionElement - 1);
    quickSort(theArray, partitionElement + 1, stopIndex);

}
```

}

void insertionSort(int* list, int start, int stop) {

```
if (stop <= 1) {

    return;

}

insertionSort(list, stop - 1);

int last = list[stop - 1];
int j = stop - 2;

while (j >= 0 && list[j] > last)
{
    list[j + 1] = list[j];
    j--;
}

list[j + 1] = last;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was in a code snippet that I hadn't posted. I overlooked a function header where I put "stop - 1" when it should've been "stop" for the full list. I was cutting it off by 1. Shows how important it is to go back over your entire code looking for even the simplest errors. I thank anyone who has looked at my question, and look forward to learning and answering questions for others. :)